# losetup refuses to detach

Tags: linux, partitioning, raspberry-pi

I've done the following several times, but now it doesn't work anymore:

1. downloaded the latest Raspbian image
2. `qemu-img resize 2017-06-21-raspbian-jessie-lite.img +300M`
3. `sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 2017-06-21-raspbian-jessie-lite.img`
4. `sudo gparted /dev/loop0`
5. using gparted, resized the fs partition to fill the empty space
6. `sudo losetup -D`
7. `truncate --size=$[(3162111+1)*512] 2017-06-21-raspbian-jessie-lite.img`

The "magic number" 3162111 is the last sector of the second partition.
Then I burned an sd-card with the new image.
It doesn't boot - it hangs on the 4 raspberries with black screen.

Of course the original one works fine.
I've noticed that `sudo losetup -a` still shows the image mounted:

```
$ sudo losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [2049]:1179664 (/home/dev/opt/2017-06-21-raspbian-jessie-lite.img), offset 48234496
```

Trying again with `sudo losetup -D` doesn't change anything.
Even `fuser -c` or `-k` does nothing useful.

I'm afraid the problem on boot is related to this.
What could I try to check now?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on amd64 Debian Buster. After you do `losetup -D` what exit value does it return? (enter `echo $?` right after `losetup -D`)

Comment: `echo $?` returns 0

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396122/loop-devices-dont-go-away-properly | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093405/losetup-d-not-working